# Google IMA HTML5 SDK API - Get the skip time remaining

Tags: google-ima

I'm working on a custom theme for VideoJS and I'm using Google IMA HTML5 SDK API to display video ads (prerolls)

Is there a way to get the time remaining before the user can click the "skip ad" (e.g. the same time that it has in the label counting down the time before the button "skip ad" is enable)

There are all these properties/methods

- player.ima3.adsManager.getAdSkippableState()
- player.ima3.adsManager.getCurrentAd() which allows for currentAd.isSkippable()

But I can't find something that gives the remaining time to skip the ad

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not possible to get the skipoffset time

"Currently at the moment, the skip button cannot be hidden.  In addition, you cannot get the linear skipoffset time through an API method.   We do have an API method for getting the offset but it is for the entire ad pod"

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ima-sdk/VtdLy_b9J_w